# Backspace removes extra space after installing delimitMate

Tags: plugin-delimitmate

I want `Backspace` key to remove only one space all the time, but after installing delimitMate, it removes extra space. Let's say I want to type the code below.

```
let hello = "some text";
```

While I'm typing this, I accidentally type extra space after `hello`, so there are two spaces between `hello` and my cursor as follows.

```
let hello  |
```

And, at this point, I decide to remove one space with `Backspace`, but it removes two spaces instead, so the cursor ends up next to `o` as in `hello` as follows.

```
let hello|
```

Now, I have to type space again to make sure there is one space between `hello` and `=`. This is redundant and I don't like this. Does anyone know how to make `Backspace` remove only one space all the time with delimitMate installed?

**Edit:**

Thanks to the comment from B Layer, I found the mapping that was causing this. After commenting out the mapping code, I was able to remove only one space with `Backspace` key, but now when I delete a matching pair, it only deletes the opening one, and the closing one stays intact.

*Before*

```
{|}
```

*Input*

```
<BS>
```

*After*

```
}
```

Comment: "`Backspace` command"? Do you just mean the backspace _key_? If so does `:imap <bs>` show anything? If so, try `:verbose imap <bs>` to see where the mapping is being created.

Comment: Yes, backspace key. I will edit it. `:verbose imap <bs>`  showed that `silent! imap <unique> <buffer> <BS> <Plug>delimitMateBS` was the mapping, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: After taking a quick look at the docs to see the intended purpose of the backspace mapping it sounds like that behavior might be a bug. I think it should only do something if you're between paired delimiters. You might want to open an issue at the plugin's github site.

Comment: (Or if it's a "feature" they might be able to tell you how to selectively disable it...whether through available configuration or by hacking the code.)

Comment: I opened an issue at https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate/issues/297. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope they get back to you. Looks like there's not a ton of activity there lately. So many open source projects suffer from their authors losing interest... :( (Though it's hard to fault someone who open sourced their work to begin with.)

Answer (score 0):

The creator of delimitMate gave me a solution that worked for me.
I'm a Rust programmer and this solution is specific for Rust files, so I don't know how this works for other files.

Add `au FileType rust set sts=0` to your neovim config file.

Now, when you press the backspace key, it only removes one space.
Take a look at the [issue](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate/issues/297) I opened at github for details, which led me to this solution.

Comment: You shouldnt have to modify the plugin. Just put the `setlocal` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/rust.vim`.

Comment: Adding `setlocal` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/rust.vim` had no effect for me. Instead, adding `au FileType rust set sts=0` to my neovim config file worked.

Comment: Well the path is different on neovim but the idea should work